# ASP.Net Control Visible=False Random Data Problem

Tags: asp.net, security, controls

Does anyone know of an issue with setting the Visible property of a control to false causing the value to change?

In the code below, the line:

```
control.Visible = dr.ParmDisplay;
```

On some servers, if the control is not visible it is not saving the value that was just set above it. We have a test server that this code works just fine, but we have a customer that the value is not saving. If the control *is* visible, it saves/shows/stores the value just fine on any server.

Is there some security patch that changes how this works??? I've Google'd it, and I don't find anything related to the visible property having this affect.

Here's the full code for this procedure:

```
protected void LoadReport()
    {

        dsReport.ReportParametersDataTable dt = objLoadXml.GetReportParameters(objReport.ReportName);
        foreach (dsReport.ReportParametersRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Control control = null;
            IParm parameterControl = null;
            if (dr.ParmType.ToUpper().StartsWith("DATERANGE"))
            {
                control = LoadControl("./UserControls/DateRange.ascx");

            }
            else if (dr.ParmType.ToUpper().StartsWith("DATE"))
            {
                control = LoadControl("./UserControls/Date.ascx");

            }
            else
            {
                control = LoadControl("./UserControls/Parameter.ascx");

            }
            control.EnableViewState = true;
            parameterControl = (IParm)control;
            parameterControl.ParmName = dr.ParmName;
            parameterControl.ParmDescription = dr.ParmDescription;
            parameterControl.ParmPickList = dr.ParmPickList.ToString();
            if (dr["ParmDefaultValue"].ToString() != "")
                parameterControl.ParmDefaultValue = dr.ParmDefaultValue;
            control.Visible = dr.ParmDisplay;
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(control);





        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: One note of clarification, ParmDefaultValue is the property that is not saving/storing correctly if the control is not visible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set a control to not visible, it does not get rendered to the browser. Therefore it will not be there on post back and the value won't make it back to the server.

If you need to persist the value w/out showing the control, store it directly in view state, or hidden input etc.

Comment: I see/understand what you are saying, but why does it work on some browsers/servers? Is there a web.config setting that can be made to override and make it work? Was there a Windows update that changed the way it works?

Comment: i don't think it ever saved the value that way (if i am understanding the question correctly). perhaps the behavior difference you're seeing is in some default value. i.e. instead of bool, make a test case with a string, and it should always be empty on postback. also, since you are dynamically adding controls, the timing of that add makes a difference in wiring that control to the page event cycle. it is possible that you added them in the past during different stages of page load?

Comment: No, absolutely no changes on the code. This same code works fine on different servers. I did put out a fix today though that simply removes the line setting the visibility and loads a different control that has the TR style of display:none set. The fix worked great. Thank you for at least confirming that the way it was being done was probably incorrect anyway. I'm beginning to think that IE sets the value to nothing where Firefox handled it just fine.